# Import Stencil JS library from another Stencil JS library

Tags: javascript, npm, web-component, stenciljs

I have two libraries of Stencil JS web components, library-a and library-b.  These are not apps, just separate npm packages of components.

I would like to use some of the components from library-a inside library-b.  How do I import components from A into B?

The StencilJS docs offer some import instructions but don't cover this particular use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically all you have to do is `npm install` (or `npm link`) the project and import it.

As far as I know there are two places you can include the import:

1. Inside a global `app.ts` which is configured as a `globalScript` in `stencil.config.ts`.
2. Inside the root component.

In your case the second option probably won't work since component libraries usually don't have a root component.

**Import inside `app.ts`**:

First, create a [global script](https://stenciljs.com/docs/config#globalscript) and configure it in your `stencil.config.ts`:

```
export const config: Config = {
  // ...
  globalScript: 'src/global/app.ts',
};
```

Then add the import inside that file. Example for Ionic Framework:

```
import '@ionic/core';
```

Now you can use the components just like any other HTML element.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Will just add small comment. It is important to have global/app.ts inside the src folder. Originally I put it to root and it wasn't working because of the script located outside the other code, not in the scope.