# Using Stenciljs Components from my other repo in my current project

Tags: import, components, bitbucket, stenciljs, stencil-component

I have two private bitbucket repos with Stenciljs components and I want to use some components from one in the other. I do not want to upload them to npm or anything of the sort. Both repos are 100% Stenciljs.

I was wondering if there is a way I can import the components I need straight from the repo. I have read and write access to both repos.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a package that's not on NPM you can add a Git URL, e.g. for Bitbucket:

```
npm install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{user}/{repo}.git
```

Then you can [import the entire package in the second project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123946/import-stencil-js-library-from-another-stencil-js-library/66137851#66137851) and let Stencil handle bundling only the used components.