# Importing stenciljs components from one project to another

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

I am baffled that I have not found an official answer anywhere, but is there a way to use `defineCustomComponents` from a stenciljs component project in another stenciljs component project? Or is it possible to import components from different packages just via the script tag?

```html
<script scr="<path-to-package>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

By default (using the `dist` or `www` output targets) a Stencil library automatically registers its components, so there's no need to call `defineCustomComponents` manually. The components themselves are lazy-loaded as soon as they're used on a page.

If you want to use components generated with Stencil in another project, you can either include the script tag, which should work for most frameworks), or for Stencil projects you can just import the package, and Stencil will handle the integration. I would recommend importing for Stencil projects since that will create a single output and also add the type information to your editor. Otherwise things like the lazy-loading code would have to be downloaded twice.

More info:

- [Stencil docs on distribution options](https://stenciljs.com/docs/distribution#distribution-options)
- [Import Stencil JS library from another Stencil JS library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66137851/1242317)